# Is there an elegant way to pass global variable through different tasks in Fabric2

Tags: python, fabric

Now, I store the global variable such as `release_path` etc in env, in order to pass to
other tasks

I want to know what is the best practice to pass variable through one task to another task.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `Connection` object has a `connect_kwargs` which is well-suited for replacing Fabric1's `env`. You can read about it [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/api/connection.html#connect-kwargs-arg)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the env dictionary in the task context for that:

```
@task
def qa(ctx):
  ctx.config.run.env['counter'] = 22
  ctx.config.run.env['conn'] = Connection('qa_host')

@task
def sign(ctx):
  print(ctx.config.run.env['counter'])
  conn = ctx.config.run.env['conn']
  conn.run('touch mike_was_here.txt')
```

And run:

```
fab2 qa sign
```